# Siri is recognising phrases from my AppIntentVocabulary.plist, but it's not using the VocabularyItemIdentifier values associated with those phrases

Tags: ios, ios10, siri, sirikit

I am working on a workout app and want to integrate SiriKit for iOS 10. I already know how to integrate SiriKit and make Siri to work with our app.

Only useful resource on this I can find is Apple's official documentation : [SiriKit iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html)

To make Siri recognise our custom vocabulary we have to add this file [image]AppIntentVocabulary.plist

But the `intent.workoutName.identifier` always returns spoken phrase instead of VocabularyItemIdentifier that is **Cardio Craze** instead of **cardio_craze_workout**

Does anyone facing this issue or found any solution for this?

Comment: Have you made progress on this one? I would be interested as I have a similar problem

Comment: @choli: No not yet, currently I am using the item phrases instead of identifiers

Comment: can you add your AppIntentVocabulary.plist to a gist so that we can copy it? It is too long to create :)

Comment: Sure @JoãoNunes: https://gist.github.com/Ajayi13/49cf1f5da7ba915fe7d7c587c97b7bd9